# Dynamically creating divs and applying values from arrays to them

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to loop through an array (palettesDIVArray) that contains arrays ( paletteOne,paletteTwo & paletteThree) and apply colors values contained in the arrays to divs (palettesDIV) that are created dynamically.

The number of palettesDIV created should be based on the number of arrays in palettesDIVArray.

Each palettesDIV should then be filled with colors from one array, for this purpouse a number of divs (palettesDIVparts) are created depdning on the number of colors contained in each palette array.

As you can see in the jsfiddle, it all works fine as long as I just target a specific div and pick specific array to apply.

Any idea of how I can modify my code so that it creates 3 divs and applies the colors from the arrays that contain colors in a more dynamic way?

https://jsfiddle.net/ccxtbpzz/6/

javascript:

```
var
divPalette,
palettePage,
contentSection,
paletteOne,
paletteTwo,
paletteThree,
paletteArray,
palettePart,
widthOfdivPalette,
palettesDIV,
palettesDIVArray,
palettesDIVparts,
divOffSetWidth,
nrOfDivParts,
widthInPixels;


//Initializing varibles and attatching functions
palettePage = document.getElementById("palettePage");
paletteOne = ["hsla(300,21%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(100,91%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(19,71%,85%,0.92)"];
paletteTwo = ["hsla(176,51%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(216,11%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(350,91%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(240,31%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(111,11%,25%,0.92)"];
paletteThree = ["hsla(276,51%,15%,0.92)", "hsla(116,20%,85%,0.32)", "hsla(150,91%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(240,31%,85%,0.92)", "hsla(111,11%,25%,0.92)"];
paletteArray = [paletteOne, paletteTwo, paletteThree];
palettesDIVArray = [];


function createPalettesDivs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < paletteArray.length; i++) {

        palettesDIV = document.createElement("div");
        palettesDIVArray.push(palettesDIV);
        palettesDIV.className = "palettesDIV";
        palettePage.appendChild(palettesDIV);

    }
}

createPalettesDivs();

function createpalettesDIVparts() {

    for (var i = 0; i < paletteArray[1].length; i++) {


        palettesDIVparts = document.createElement("div");
        palettesDIVArray[0].appendChild(palettesDIVparts);
        palettesDIVparts.className = "palettesDIVparts";
        palettesDIVparts.style.backgroundColor = paletteArray[2][i];

        //Setting width of each palettesDIVparts
        divOffSetWidth = palettesDIV.offsetWidth;
        nrOfDivParts = paletteArray[1].length;
        widthInPixels = divOffSetWidth / nrOfDivParts;
        palettesDIVparts.style.width = widthInPixels / divOffSetWidth * 100 + "%";
    }    
}

createpalettesDIVparts();
```

html:

```
<div id="palettePage"></div>
```

css:

```
#palettePage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.palettesDIV {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2.5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.palettesDIVparts {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you closer although I think the whole thing is a bit overcomplicated.

```
function createpalettesDIVparts() {

  palettesDIVArray.forEach(function(div, divIdx){ 
    // define pallet being used to make it easier to read throughout function 
    var pallet = paletteArray[divIdx]
    for (i = 0; i < pallet.length; i++) {


        var  palettesDIVparts = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(palettesDIVparts);
        palettesDIVparts.className = "palettesDIVparts";
        palettesDIVparts.style.backgroundColor = pallet[i];

        //Setting width of palettesDIVparts
        divOffSetWidth = palettesDIV.offsetWidth;
        nrOfDivParts = pallet.length;
        widthInPixels = divOffSetWidth / nrOfDivParts;
        palettesDIVparts.style.width = widthInPixels / divOffSetWidth * 100 + "%";


    }
  });

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ccxtbpzz/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How come you think its over complicated? Suggestions on alternave approaches?

Comment: should be able to take out the middle step of creating an array of `div's`

Comment: create and populate at the same time then you don't have so many arrays to loop over

Answer (score 1):

I updated the jsfiddle to apply the color pallets across all three divs

https://jsfiddle.net/ccxtbpzz/8/

I simply added a second loop to your function `createpalettesDIVparts()` and used its index as a reference like so:

```
function createpalettesDIVparts() {

for (x = 0; x < paletteArray.length; x++) {
    for (i = 0; i < paletteArray[x].length; i++) {


        palettesDIVparts = document.createElement("div");
        palettesDIVArray[x].appendChild(palettesDIVparts);
        palettesDIVparts.className = "palettesDIVparts";
        palettesDIVparts.style.backgroundColor = paletteArray[x][i];

        //Setting width of palettesDIVparts
        divOffSetWidth = palettesDIV.offsetWidth;
        nrOfDivParts = paletteArray[x].length;
        widthInPixels = divOffSetWidth / nrOfDivParts;
        palettesDIVparts.style.width = widthInPixels / divOffSetWidth * 100 + "%";
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.